# definite integral- how to solve. I know the substitution.

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I know the substitution but how should I continue? [image]

$$\int_0^1 x\sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}}dx$$

Comment: Hint: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassSubstitution.html

Comment: Let $x=\cos^22t.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way - by setting $x=u^2$, then $u=\frac{1-v}{1+v}$ and $v=z^2$, we are left with:

$$ \int_{0}^{1}2u^3\sqrt{\frac{1-u}{1+u}}\,du = 4\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-v)^3}{(1+v)^5}\sqrt{v}\,dv =8\int_{0}^{1}\frac{z^2(1-z^2)^3}{(1+z^2)^5}\,dz$$
Then by applying integration by parts we get
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-9 z^2+15 z^4-7 z^6}{(1+z^2)^4}\,dz=-7\,I_1+36\,I_2-60\,I_3+32\,I_4 $$
with $I_k=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dz}{(1+z^2)^k}.$ These integrals can be computed through differentiation under the integral sign, since for any $a>0$ we have
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{a\,dz}{a+z^2}=\frac{\text{arccot}\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}} $$
hence $I_1=\frac{\pi}{4}, I_2=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\pi}{8}, I_3=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3\pi}{32}, I_4=\frac{11}{48}+\frac{5\pi}{64}$. Summarizing,

> $$ \int_{0}^{1}x\sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt x}{1+\sqrt x}}\,dx = \color{red}{\frac{4}{3}-\frac{3\pi}{8}}.$$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

For $x\in [0,1]$, $\theta\in [0,\pi/2]$.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt x}{1+\sqrt x}}&=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(\theta)}{1+\cos(\theta)}}\\\\&=\sqrt{\frac{(1-\cos(\theta))^2}{1-\cos^2(\theta)}}\\\\&=\frac{1-\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_0^1 x\sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}}dx$$

Let $\sqrt{x} = \cos\theta,\theta \in (0,\pi/2)$

$$\int_0^1 x\sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}}dx$$

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^2x \frac{1-\cos x}{\sin x}2\cos x\sin xdx$$

$$2\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^3x -\cos^4 xdx$$
We could use the [following formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193435/prove-int-cosn-x-dx-frac1n-cosn-1x-sin-x-fracn-1n-int-cos) to calculate the final result:
$$\int\cos^n x \ dx = \frac{1}n \cos^{n-1}x \sin x + \frac{n-1}{n}\int\cos^{n-2} x \ dx$$

Comment: Is there a sign error somewhere ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Notice that the sign is canceled by the integration bound change. When changing from $(0,1)$ to $(0, \pi/2)$, we introduced a negative sign, when doing $d\cos^2x$, we have another negative sign - the two negative signs cancel each other.

Comment: I apologize ! I am just stupid. Cheers. By the way, nice solution (+1).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici No worries, and thank you for your interest in my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a less brute-force way to get to the desired subsitution
$$\int_0^1 x\sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}}dx\stackrel{x \to x^2}{=} 2\int_0^1 x^3\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}dx$$
The substitution $u = \frac{1-x}{1+x}$ is now obvious, yielding
$$-2\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1-u}{1+u}\right)^3u^{-1/2}\left(\frac{1-u}{(u+1)^2} - \frac{1}{u+1}\right)du$$
$$-4\int_0^1 \frac{(u-1)^3 \sqrt u}{(u + 1)^5}du$$
From here we have obvious partial fraction decomposition, which could also clearly be solved with a simple tangent substitution. A bit tedius (subsitute $v=u+1$ to avoid clutter if desired) but should yield the desired answer quite cleanly.

Comment: Isn't this a little too lengthy?

Comment: @Sid To some degree, yes. I did it pretty quickly nevertheless... all the substitutions are obvious. Mostly I just wanted to attack this without trig substitution :)

Comment: Yes it's good to approach from different directions. The integral is lengthy even with trignometric substitution

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you set $\sqrt{x} = \cos\theta$, then $$\frac{1-\cos\theta}{1+\cos\theta} = \tan\frac{\theta}{2}.$$

Comment: Yes..so? How will your correlate presence of $\cos ^2 \theta$?