# Why is reduction formula of $\int \cos^n (x) dx$ restricted to n>1?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int\cos^n x \ dx = \frac{1}n \cos^{n-1}x \sin x + \frac{n-1}{n}\int\cos^{n-2} x \ dx$$

is valid for n>1

The derivation of the reduction formula is well-discussed on the forum [e.g](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193435/prove-int-cosn-x-dx-frac1n-cosn-1x-sin-x-fracn-1n-int-cos?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I can't find anywhere explaining why it is only valid for n>1. Can someone explain?

Comment: Are you sure it's $n>1$, not $n>0$?

Comment: That is valid for $n=1$, just not very interesting.

Comment: interesting... My problem sheet did say n>1, but i got it to work for n=1. I understand why it does not work for n=0 and below, thanks guys

Comment: $n=0$? Thou shalt not divide by zero!