# $ \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0} \cos^nx \ dx = \frac{n-1}{n} \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0} \cos^{n-2}x \ dx$ for $n \in \{ \mathbb{N} > 2 \}$ proof

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, proof-writing

I need to prove that:

$$ \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0} \cos^n x \, \mathrm dx = \frac{n-1}{n} \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0} \cos^{n-2} x \, \mathrm dx$$

for $n \in \{\mathbb{N} > 2\}$

I know that the integrals will not disappear if we take a derivative of both sides of equation even though they are taken on interval with 0.

I thought therefore that the only / the easiest way to prove that must be through induction. I have the basis (for n = 3 we get):

$$ \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0} \cos^3 x \, \mathrm dx = \frac{2}{3} \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0} \cos x\, \mathrm dx$$
(integration of the LHS)
$$\left[\sin x-\frac{1}{3}\sin^3 x\right]^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 = \frac{2}{3}\left[\cos x \right]^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \to 1 - \frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{3}$$

And that works. However, I don't know how to do the hard part of induction since I don't even see that type of simple regularity of changes in the integral of $cos(x)$ that would come with changes of $n$.

Therefore I'm not sure how to do the proof (which should be easy according to my book).

Comment: Did you try integration by parts?

Comment: No. Do you mean as for that induction? Or without induction at all (to go from LHS to RHS)?

Comment: Typically reduction formulas can be tackled with integration by parts...

Comment: @mathbb Without the induction at all. Write $\cos ^{n} x$ as $\cos ^{n-1} x \cos x$ and proceed by parts.

Comment: The question and answer of [Prove $\int\cos^n x \ dx = \frac{1}n \cos^{n-1}x \sin x + \frac{n-1}{n}\int\cos^{n-2} x \ dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193435/prove-int-cosn-x-dx-frac1n-cosn-1x-sin-x-fracn-1n-int-cos) address your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it by parts as $$I_n=\int \cos^{n-1}x \cos x dx=\cos^{n-1}x \sin x -(n-1)\int\cos^{n-2}x \sin^2 x ~dx$$
Use $\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x$.
$$\implies I_n=\cos^{n-1}x \sin x-(n-1)\int\cos^{n-2}x~ dx+(n-1)I$$
$$\implies -nI_n=\cos^{n-1}x \sin x-(n-1)I_{n-2}.$$
Put the limits to get $$I_n=\frac{n-1}{n}I_{n-2}$$